# Binary independent variables with missing values. Create dummy variables or not?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, logistic, sas

I am developing a prognostic model to predict an outcome. I have few binary variables with missing values, see below example. Is it better if I create dummy variables out of the below Gender variable in the model or keep it as it is? I have 79 binary variables like this. Please let me know which is best.

```
Gender
M
F
M
M
.
F
M
F
M
F
.
F
.
M
```

Answer (score 1):

Software will 'dummy out' the subcategories for free. You should see estimates with the values appended to the variable name (e.g., `GenderM`, `GenderF`, etc.). R forces one category to be the referent.

I don't have a problem with recommending the following code to you:

```
glm(outcome ~ gender, family = “binomial”, data = ...)
```

I should note, however, that your output might be a bit inscrutable with sundry categorical predictors. To illustrate, suppose some of your categorical variables have more than two levels. Do you want estimates for all subcategories? A subcategory might exist with scanty observations, resulting in imprecise estimates.

I recommend creating your dummies explicitly, though I recognize this could become unwieldy with nearly 80 predictors. For example, create a variable `male` and assign it a value of 1 if `Gender == M`, 0 otherwise. You might have to do a little more work if you're preserving your missing values.

```
df %>%
  mutate(male = ifelse(gender == "M", 1,
                       ifelse(gender == "F", 0, NA))
         )
```

Again, this approach requires significant effort on your part with nearly 80 binary inputs. The principal benefit is you will know exactly what your dummies represent in your output. For example, suppose you instantiate other dummy inputs such as whether a person was arrested at least once over their life course (i.e., `arrest == 1`), whether they were raised in an urban environment (i.e., `urban == 1`), or their diagnosis of type 2 diabetes within the last 12 months (i.e.,  `diabetes == 1`). Such variables simply represent the *presence* (i.e., `value == 1` or *absence* (i.e., `value == 0`) of these particular characteristics. Your output will clearly display what each effect is representing. See the example below:

```
glm(outcome ~ male + arrest + urban + diabetes, family = “binomial”, data = ...)
```

This explicit approach will come in handy when you write up your findings later. If time is of the essence and the recodes prove too labor intensive, then I hope it is clear from the value labels what each category represents, and which level was absorbed into your intercept.

As far as missingness is concerned, most of R's canned regression functions will automatically drop missing values without any additional work on your part. However, if a large proportion of missingness is observed across all your inputs, then listwise deleting all missing values could remove more rows than you can afford.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have missing data ... From your tags I'm guessing that you're trying to do a logistic regression. If you set gender up as a binary variable then you have the option of marking both your binary variables as False where gender is missing if that makes sense in your model. E.g. interpret Gender as "The gender is known to be M/F" thus False just means that the statement isn't true, hence you could mark both variables as False in the event of missing data. Otherwise you'll just have to take out all the rows with missing data which may make your model worse overall given that you've got other variables in the mix.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. Do you think I should create dummy variables) as Gender_F, Gender_M and Gender_Missing? or just leave as it is and run the model. Yes I am implementing logistic regression model.

Comment: I'd suggest just Gender_F,Gender_M and then set both to False if its missing.

Comment: Do you only have two values for gender?

Comment: Thank you @emiru for the suggestion

Comment: Hi Thomas, yes only 2 values Male and female but there are missing values as well.

Comment: Do you have a lot of *missingness*? Or, I should say, is it a problem?